# VPN with Debian without FortClient

Tags: linux, debian, vpn

My company has recently switched to using FortiClient for VPN. We have instructions for Windows and Mac, but not Linux (Debian in my case). The Linux version of the FortiClient app does not need to have the same settings as the Windows. So I then went through trying to use NetworkManager to set it up with L2tP & StrongSwan.

So of the configurations that we were given for Windows FortiClient:

- Choosing IPSEC VPN
- Entering the VPN address in Remote Gateway
- Entering something the Pre-Shared Key
- Entering something in the Local ID

Then, when you actually log in you're suppose to a pin.

I've tried setting up what I think to be correct (see screenshot) but I think I'm missing something. I've tried various different settings and none work. The problem is, am not sure what corresponds in Linux to what is filled out on the Windows FortiClient, or if I'm pursuing the right direction.

Does anyone have any guidance on what needs setup on Linux to emulate those settings on Windows?

Thanks!

[image: Image of VPN]

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken FortiClient is compatible with both FortiGate's IPsec VPN and SSL VPN.

For FortiGate IPsec VPN you can try network-manager-vpnc.

For FortiGate SSL VPN you can try network-manager-fortisslvpn.

network-manager-l2tp is a L2TP VPN client with optional IPsec IKEv1 support and is different to FortiGate's IPsec which doesn't use L2TP.